# how do i make a query to search by date, the DATE query odsent work when i try to use it, even with TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CY0s.png)

im trying to run a query to factor by the date but i cant get it to work. im running this on Oracle. any suggestions would be helpful.

i tried
DATE = '15-OCT-2015';

BUT THAT DIDNT WORK SO I TRIED

TO_DATE('15-APR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY');

BUT THAT DIDNT WORK EITHER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is happening because Oracle is treating `date` as a keyword, not as a column.

Can you try accessing it via double quotes:

```sql
select 
    t1.*
from 
    orders t1
where 
    t1.customer_num = '126' and t1."date" = date'2015-10-15'
```

Comment: i jsut figured out the issue, youre right but i dint enter the right adress and had been writing in the wrong thing. thanyou*facepalm*